# Calling native java code from JS with cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, webview

I can successfully call native java code from JS in a Cordova 5.4.0 application using @JavascriptInterface. But after adding cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview, it is not working. After searching, I have modify my code as:-

```
public class MainActivity extends CordovaActivity{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      loadUrl("file://android_assets/www/index.html");
      ((XWalkView)appView.getEngine().getView()).addJavascriptInterface(this,"MainActivity");
    }

   @JavascriptInterface
   public void getMessage() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "this is my Toast message!!!  =)",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }

}
```

And calling native code from js as:

```
window.MainActivity.getMessage();
```

I also imported

```
import org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface;
import org.xwalk.core.XWalkView;
```

Also tried replacing

```
@JavascriptInterface
```

with

```
@org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface
```

Now the app even not opening. It crash. Help Plz.

Comment: Any exception message?

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cloudlabz.allsaletags/com.cloudlabz.allsaletags.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: addJavascriptInterface

Comment: why don't you just use cordova plugins instead?

Comment: Yes, at last, after spending 1.5 months on this, I have to use plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Calling the `addJavaScriptInterface()` inside the `onXWalkReady()` instead of doing this in the onCreate() callback solved this issue to me.

P.S.: Method chaining is not a good practice.

Answer (score -2):

plese update `config.xml`
 preference `name="android-minSdkVersion" value="16"` 
into 
preference `name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17`
and use
import `org.xwalk.core.JavascriptInterface;`
use cordova version **6.3.0 or updated**